# NoReverseMatch Because Not Found 1 Pattern in the Base.html

Tags: django, django-templates

I understand that my template is not defined, so I need to pass the template but the template I want to use the url is the base.html, so how to pass the model?

Model:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
 owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
 related_name='quizzes')
 name = models.CharField(verbose_name='nome',max_length=255)
```

url to put in base.html:

```
{% url 'teachers:quiz_results' quiz.pk %}
```

Obs:
The base.html has no view because it is extended by another page

Comment: Please can you post the code from your models.py  url.py and views.py files.

Comment: We need to see the context in view.

Comment: The base.html has no view because it is extended by another page

Comment: @DaviLuis Please post urls.py